# Call WCF Resfull methods with using OAUTH 2.0

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, wcf-rest

I am looking for any article or forum thread, where I could find information how to make oauth 2.0 authentication. Especially I have MVC 3 application and WCF Restfull API. And I have to call API methods from web app with using oauth 2.0 protocol authentication. But I could not find any information about it. After googling I see only results how to develop clients for facebook, linkedin, google etc.. Any help would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/). It has a client library which you can easily install from [NuGet here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.Ultimate/4.3.3.13295).
Using `DotNetOpenAuth` all the OAuth plumbing is handled behind the scenes.

**DotNetOpenAuth:**

When you install the NuGet Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.Ultimate/4.3.3.13295

You can setup an OAuth client like this:

```
var authorizationServerDescription = new AuthorizationServerDescription
{
    ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20,
    TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://yourUrl/token"),
    AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://yourUrl/authorize")
};

var client = new WebServerClient(authorizationServerDescription, "ClientIdentifier", "ClientSecret");
```

Then you can request a `IAuthorizationState` like this:

```
// Resource Owner Password Flow
client.ExchangeUserCredentialForToken("userName", "password");

// Client Credential Flow
client.GetClientAccessToken();
```

The IAuthorizationState contains the `AccessToken` you can use to Authorize against your Api. If a RefreshToken is provided you can also refresh your authorization using:

```
client.RefreshAuthorization(AuthorizationState);
```

**ThinkTecture:**

Alternatively you could use `Thinktecture.IdentityModel`. If you chose to use Thinktectures IdentityModel be sure to check out this post: [Introducing OAuth2 Code Flow and Refresh Token Support in Thinktecture IdentityServer](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/03/15/introducing-oauth2-code-flow-and-refresh-token-support-in-thinktecture-identityserver/). Which not only explains how to set up an OAuth Token Server using Thinktecture, but how to use the client as well including a code sample. Ofcourse you can use this client to validate against another OAuth 2.0 server as long as the parameters are implemented according to the OAuth specifications.

**OAuth 2.0 Playground**
If you want to have a better look at the OAuth 2.0 flow, be sure to check out Google's [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). I think that a lot of people don't know that it is possible to test your own server with it. Just push the 'settings' icon in the top right and set:

> OAuth endpoints: Custom

And you're good to go.